# Why does a summary() call on a GLM model give me T rather than F values?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression

I constructed a quasi-Poisson model ("`mod`") with two predictors and an interaction term using `glm()`. One of the predictors is continuous (counts) and one is categorical (mean size), the response is, of course, continuous (also counts). When I call `summary(mod)`, I get a list of T-values, but, I would have expected F-values. Why does `summary()` return T-values for such a model?

Comment: Sad to see they've gone back to calling those t-values in `glm`, which they really aren't unless you're fitting a normal linear regression model.  For a good while they were calling them z-values in `glm` in R (which is the asymptotic approximation that can be justified for the general case).

Comment: @Glen_b The documentation says "This third column is labelled t ratio if the dispersion is estimated, and z ratio if the dispersion is known (or fixed by the family). A fourth column gives the two-tailed p-value corresponding to the t or z ratio based on a Student t or Normal reference distribution. (It is possible that the dispersion is not known and there are no residual degrees of freedom from which to estimate it. In that case the estimate is NaN.)"

Comment: Interesting that it bases it on whether the dispersion is estimated, but I still don't see any formal justification for treating it as t rather than z.

Comment: SAS seems to call them t-values also. I found an example [here](https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2015/10/14/estimating-quasi-poisson-regression-with-glimmix-in-sas/) and [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glimmix_examples07.htm).

Comment: @Glen_b In this thread on R-help, Prof. Ripley provides a reference: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/100878.html Unfortunately, I don't have it at hand. In any case, he recommends some alternatives such as `drop1` or using profile confidence intervals .

Comment: @Glen_b So - How should one report the results given by `summary()` in this case? I assume the P-values correspond to the printed t (or z)-ratios, but Prof Brian Ripley's comments seem to suggest otherwise. As well, where should I find the DF? I can't use the DF from `ANOVA()`, as those (I assume) will be from F tests...

Comment: @Roland Thanks -- however, I couldn't spot any place that the discussion in McCullagh and Nelder might be.

Comment: @JKO When labelled as 't value', the p-values come from using t-distributions. I still have not seen a justification for using a t that is demonstrated (or even reasonably well-motivated) to be better than the asymptotic z (for example in the case of a quasibinomial). However, if we're assuming such a argument exists, the df would be obtained in essentially the same fashion as for a linear model, so you can obtain the df from that of the residual deviance (you can confirm this is what R does readily enough by fitting a gamma glm)